# Bootstrapping variance in R gives weird shaped distribution- how to obtain confidence intervals?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, confidence-interval, variance, bootstrap

this is the first time I've used bootstrapping so it's quite basic!

I'm trying to obtain confidence intervals for the standardised variance- defined as the variance over the square of the mean- across two samples of 12 values each. I'm using a basic bootstrapping technique where I resample 10,000 sets of 12 directly from my observed data with replacement and then calculate standardised variance across each of those bootstrapped samples.

The problem I'm having is that the distribution of standardised variances is weird and lumpy- it shows illusory fine structure. A histogram for the values used for each step in the calculation is shown below: mean, mean squared, variance, variance over mean squared. You can see that the lumpiness appears to be introduced when variance is calculated, and worsen when variance is divided by mean squared in the final step. The two colours each represent one of my original samples of 12.

[mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vr3GR.png) //
[mean squared](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTKam.png) //
[variance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFhWA.png) //
[variance over mean squared](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTCUN.png)

My questions are:

- Why does this happen? All the 'introduction to bootstrapping' stuff says it can be used for variances, so there must be ways around it?
- How much of a problem is this if I want to calculate confidence intervals? Is it still valid to use the median and quantiles of this distribution?
- Can I apply some sort of post-hoc smoothing to the distribution of variances, or is there something else I should do?

Thank you!

Comment: You have discovered one of the many reasons why bootstrapping cannot generally be expected to work with small datasets. Unless this is a learning exercise, it may be pointless to use these results to compute confidence intervals.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm surprised because all the guides I've read online have implied that 10+ is normally fine?

Comment: Normally fine? In your case it is fine for the mean. So that's good. Among the assumptions of bootstrapping is that the observed realisations are a good representation of the underlying distribution. Either they are not (which is the likely option) or that is your true distribution. Note that even large numbers of observations do not necessarily lead to normally distributed variances, whereas means do: `hist(replicate(10000, sd(sample(c(1,100), 10000, TRUE))))`  vs  `hist(replicate(1000, mean(sample(c(1,100), 1000, TRUE))))`